# Create div tag dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a DIV dynamically and place it into another DIV when a button is clicked.

So far I've managed to create a new DIV on button_click, however I don't know how to place the new DIV object into a specific DIV tag as a child.

Here's my code which is within the button's click event.

```
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl dynDiv = new    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
   dynDiv.ID = "dynDivCode" + i.ToString();
   dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Gray");
   dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "20px");
   dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "300px");

   dynDiv.InnerHtml = "I was created using Code Behind";

   this.Controls.Add(dynDiv);
```

Any suggestions please?
 thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your specific existing div should be server control. For example: `Panel`. Then you can add as a child to the `Controls` collection of the panel.

Comment: i dont know how to add the div into the panel using c# any idea

Comment: Like you described in your sample but instead of `this.Controls.Add(dynDiv);` use your panel control `myPanel.Controls.Add(dynDiv);`

Comment: but in this div is created any where on the page. specif location  is not defined e.g creat a panel in aspx file and now want to add div tag in that panel dynamicly

Comment: Didn't get the problem. If you are creating control dynamically you need to add to some controls collection. It can be `Panel`, `Page` and any other container control. You can't add control on the server side to the not server control.

Comment: You are not getting my question please look at this example.i have created this <div id="abc"> </div> tag now want to add some more div in this div dynamicly the problem is dont know how it colud

Comment: Add `runat="server"` to this div and then you will be able to add controls from the server side: `abc.Controls.Add(..)`.